# Suppress pytest warnings for other peoples code only

Tags: pytest

I'm trying out `pytest` for the first time. How do I suppress warnings issued about other peoples code that my code depends on without suppressing warnings about my own code?

Right now I have this in my `pytest.ini` so I don't have to see pytest warn me about some deprecation on the `jsonschema` package that I'm using.

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

But now if I write anything in my own code that should fire of a deprecation warning I'll miss it.

Answer (score 9):

The syntax for pytest-warning is `action:message:category:module:lineno`. You can use this config for ignoring only jsonschema:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:jsonschema
```

You can also use regex in those fields. If you want to exclude all warnings except yours:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:!yourtestmodule
```

Pytest uses the same filterwarning as python. You can learn more about python warnings here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-filter

Source: https://github.com/fschulze/pytest-warnings/blob/master/pytest_warnings/__init__.py#L18

Comment: This seems to not be OK anymore, the correct use here is `ignore::DeprecationWarning:(?!yourtestmodule)` as the last value is a regexp

Comment: @RomualdBrunet this should be the accepted answer, please consider to turn the comment into an answer and also to explain the negative lookahead. Thank you so much for an ignore line that actually works and lets me ignore other project's sloppiness.