# How do you read selenium 4 stack traces?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pytest, stack-trace

I just upgraded our pytest with selenium automation framework to Selenium 4 and am seeing a new kind of stack trace when tests fail their waits (See below). I don't quite know what to search for and can't find answers anywhere on this.

I have two questions:

1. How am I supposed to read this?
2. Is there any way you know of to remove this from exceptions so it doesn't print out? It's kind of distracting and takes up space from the useful parts of the error message.

Thanks for any help!

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#NewConversation > div:nth-child(3) > label > input[type=text] > a"}
E         (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
E       Stacktrace:
E       0   chromedriver                        0x0000000102c19079 chromedriver + 4444281
E       1   chromedriver                        0x0000000102ba5403 chromedriver + 3970051
E       2   chromedriver                        0x0000000102840038 chromedriver + 409656
E       3   chromedriver                        0x00000001028762fd chromedriver + 631549
E       4   chromedriver                        0x0000000102876581 chromedriver + 632193
E       5   chromedriver                        0x00000001028a84f4 chromedriver + 836852
E       6   chromedriver                        0x00000001028937bd chromedriver + 751549
E       7   chromedriver                        0x00000001028a6221 chromedriver + 827937
E       8   chromedriver                        0x0000000102893683 chromedriver + 751235
E       9   chromedriver                        0x0000000102869a45 chromedriver + 580165
E       10  chromedriver                        0x000000010286aa95 chromedriver + 584341
E       11  chromedriver                        0x0000000102bea55d chromedriver + 4253021
E       12  chromedriver                        0x0000000102bef3a1 chromedriver + 4273057
E       13  chromedriver                        0x0000000102bf416f chromedriver + 4292975
E       14  chromedriver                        0x0000000102befdea chromedriver + 4275690
E       15  chromedriver                        0x0000000102bc954f chromedriver + 4117839
E       16  chromedriver                        0x0000000102c09ed8 chromedriver + 4382424
E       17  chromedriver                        0x0000000102c0a05f chromedriver + 4382815
E       18  chromedriver                        0x0000000102c208d5 chromedriver + 4475093
E       19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8150774e1 _pthread_start + 125
E       20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff815072f6b thread_start + 15

/Users/randomguy/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:247: NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)- instead, please paste them in as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado! Sorry about that. I fixed it :)

Comment: You can use what's suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57730488/2312300) to suppress selenium error messages in the output. As far as reading is concerned, it's coming from chromedriver binary. If you have experience with debugging c++ app and gdb, you can use the stacktrace to debug the error. In your case, you should probably debug with selenium itself since it's not a chromedriver issue.